# Grab all the rows that have the max price within 10 years of the minimum date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was trying to optimize this particular query, but I am having some trouble, this was the best I could come up with honestly. I am trying to grab all the rows that have the max price within 10 years of the minimum date.

```
Select * from person p join orders o 
on p.id=o.id
where o.orderdate - (select min(orderdate) from orders)<=3650 
and price = 
(Select o.price
from person p join orders o 
on p.id=o.id
where o.orderdate - (select min(orderdate) from orders)<=3650
order by price desc limit 1)
```

Also any resources that can help me think out of the box would be appreciated, mostly just trying to learn here.

Tables -

[image: Orders]

[image: Person]

Comment: All rows of what?

Answer (score 0):

This gets information on every `order` that had a `max(price)` with an `orderdate` within ten years of a `min(orderdate)`

```
with orderinfo as (
  select id, 
         first_value(orderdate) over (partition by id
                                          order by date) as first_order_date,
         first_value(orderdate) over (partition by id
                                          order by price desc) as max_price_order_date
    from orders
)
select p.*, o.*
  from orderinfo oi
  join orders o
    on o.id = oi.id
  join person p
    on p.id = o.id
 where oi.max_price_order_date - oi.first_order_date < interval '10 years'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select op.*
from (select . . .   -- list the columns here
             min(o.order_date) over (partition by id) as min_order_date,
             first_value(o.order_date) over (partition by id order by price desc, order_date asc) as max_price_order_date
      from person p join
           orders o 
           on p.id = o.id
     ) op
where max_price_order_date < min_order_date + interval '10 year'
```